# How do I compare two strings in Forth?

Tags: string, string-comparison, forth

And can I do it in an `if` statement or should I make a helper boolean variable? Here's the code I have so far. By the way, `IOX@` is to get input from the user.

```
: var
compile: VARIABLE
complile: ;

: lock
compile: var realPass$
compile: realPass$ "password" !
compile: ." Enter Password: "
compile: var pass$
compile: IOX@ pass$ !
compile: var match
compile: realPass$=pass$ match ! Unknown token: realPass$=pass$
```

Comment: user2302197: what flavour of Forth are you using?

Answer (score 6):

The ANS FORTH word to compare strings is [`COMPARE (c-addr_1 u_1 c-addr_2 u_2 -- n)`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Memory-Blocks.html#index-compare-_0040var_007b-c_002daddr1-u1-c_002daddr2-u2-_002d_002d-n--_007d--string-979). In FORTH a string is created with the `s"` word, and a string consists of a memory address and a length. This means that when you're comparing strings, you're providing to `COMPARE` the memory address and length of both strings.

The result of `COMPARE` is as follows: `0` if the two strings are equal, `-1` for less-than, `1` for greater than. This is same as other languages that provide a comparator, or comparison operator. **Note**, in FORTH `true` is `-1`, so there is no value to checking the binary return of `compare`.

Generally Forth eschews explicit variables in favor of using the stack so using it with `IF` directly without an extra variable is fine.

```
: PWCHECK
  COMPARE
  IF ." Entry denied."
  ELSE ." Welcome friend." THEN
  CR
;

S" Hello" ok
S" Goodbye" ok
PWCHECK You are not wanted here. ok
S" Howdy"  ok
S" Howdy"  ok
PWCHECK Welcome friend. ok
```

Comment: Your sample output is misleading ;-)